# How do I use 'WHERE' from VersionOne JAVA SDK

Tags: java, api, rest, versionone

I have a query like the following,

`/rest-1.v1/Data/TeamRoom?sel=Name,Team,Participants.@Count&where=Team='Team:4250032'`

How do I do the same from the VersionOne Java SDK ?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.

```
IAssetType assetType = _metaModel.getAssetType("TeamRoom");
Query query = new Query(assetType);
IAttributeDefinition team = assetType.getAttributeDefinition("Team");
IAttributeDefinition name = assetType.getAttributeDefinition("Name");
IAttributeDefinition count = assetType.getAttributeDefinition("Participants.@Count");
IFilterTerm teamName = new TokenTerm("Team='Team:4250032'");
query.getSelection().add(team);
query.getSelection().add(name);
query.getSelection().add(count);
query.setFilter(teamName);

QueryResult result = _services.retrieve(query);
```